# Flutter Share Image/File ( mimeType issue )

Tags: flutter, dart, mime-types

So i need to share an image to another application with Flutter, i use [esys_flutter_share 1.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share#-installing-tab-) plugin

```
Future<void> _shareImage(int index) async {
    final filename = _imageList[index].split("/")[2];
    try {
      final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(_imageList[index]);
      await Share.file(
          'esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png',
          text: '$filename');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

This is the same code from the example page, share my image from my application to another application the only problem that Android/Ios doesn't recognize the mimeType that is an image and shares as a text (tried on Ios simulator and even on real ios phone)

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xSgr.png)
[Screenshot how i need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6pt8.jpg)

Tried 'image/png' , 'image/jpg' ecc, always share the file like a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

share_extend plugin for iOS and Android for sharing text, image, video and files.

use:

https://pub.dev/packages/share_extend#-installing-tab-

instead of:

https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share#-installing-tab-

First, add share_extend as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
share_extend: "^1.1.7"
```

Add the following key to your info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist for saving shared images to photo library.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>describe why your app needs access to write photo library</string>
```

If your project needs read and write permissions for sharing external storage file, please add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml, located in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

import

```
import 'package:share_extend/share_extend.dart';
```

share text

```
ShareExtend.share("Enter Text Here", "text"); //don't change second parameter it's 
//defining the type of file to share.
```

share image

```
ShareExtend.share("Enter Image path Here", "image"); //don't change second parameter 
//it's defining the type of file to share.
```

share video

```
ShareExtend.share("Enter Video path Here", "video"); //don't change second parameter 
//it's defining the type of file to share.
```

share file

```
ShareExtend.share("Enter File path Here", "file"); //don't change second parameter 
//it's defining the type of file to share.
```

You can also share multiple images using this library.

Answer (score -1):

Found my issue with , if i let the let the optional String Text empty, the plugin shares the file as and image file, example:

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/p1.jpg');
      await Share.file(
          'Preset image', '$filename.jpg', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), '',
          text: '');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Ef5.png)

Instead if i write anything in the optional description string "text: 'My optional text.'" when i share i get the file shared like a text like as the original issue.